# Angle between vectors a and b if a + 3b is perpendicular to....

Tags: linear-algebra

Determine the angle between vectors $a$ and $b( a \ne 0, b \ne0)$ if $a + 3b$ is perpendicular to $2a - b$ and $a + 7b$ is perpendicular to $2a + b$.

I've done this:

$(a + 3b) \cdot (2a - b) = 0$
$\dots 5a⋅b = 3b⋅b - 2a⋅a$

$(a + 7b) \cdot (2a + b) = 0$
$\cdots 15a⋅b = -2 a⋅a - 7b\cdot b$

which gives me:

$a⋅b = (-(b⋅b + a⋅a))/5$

$cos(\theta) = (-b - a)/5$

Now I'm not really sure how to proceed

Comment: What does "!=" mean?

Comment: Does not equal ... the vectors are `not` the 0 vector

Comment: You are nearly done if you replace your last expression for $\cos(\theta)$ by the correct $\cos(\theta) = a.b/||a||||b||$.

Comment: @EthanBolker so cos(θ) =  (−(b⋅b+a⋅a))/(5⋅|a|⋅|b|) ?

Comment: \neq is the MathJaX code for not equal to, the above is more of a programming symbol than a math symbol, just for future reference

Comment: @Maxposive That's a correct next step.There's still more work required to find the lengths. See the answers posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $$5a\cdot b=3b\cdot b-2a\cdot a$$ $$15a\cdot b=-7b\cdot b-2a\cdot a$$so subtract the 2nd equation from the first to get $$-10a\cdot b=10b\cdot b\Rightarrow b\cdot b=-a\cdot b$$

Also $$35a\cdot b=21b\cdot b-14a\cdot a$$ $$45a\cdot b=-21b\cdot b-6a\cdot a\Rightarrow80a\cdot b=-20a\cdot a$$ so similarly $$a\cdot a=-4a\cdot b$$

Then finally

$$\cos\theta=\frac{a\cdot b}{|a||b|}\\
\cos\theta=\frac{a\cdot b}{\sqrt{(a\cdot a) (b\cdot b)}}=\frac{a\cdot b}{\sqrt{(-4a\cdot b)(-a\cdot b)}}=\frac{1}{2}.$$

So $\theta=\pi/3$.

Comment: Now I see, I followed another example where they added the equations instead of subtracting them. Such a simple mistake...

Answer (score 1):

$$5\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}=3b^2-2a^2$$
$$15\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}=-7b^2-2a^2$$
Then $$10\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}=-10b^2$$
and $$80\vec{a}\cdot\vec{b}=-20a^2$$
Then
$$|\vec{a}|\cdot|\vec{b}|\cos \phi=-b^2$$
and
$$|\vec{a}|\cdot|\vec{b}|\cos \phi=-\frac14a^2$$
Then $$\cos^2\phi=\frac14$$

Comment: I follow until the last step, could you explain how you get to that conclusion?

Comment: Multiplied (LHS)*(LHS)=(RHS)*(RHS)

Comment: $$a^2b^2\cos ^2 \phi = -b^2(-\frac14a^2)$$